# AVAudioEngine & AVAudioPlayerNode didFinish method like AVAudioPlayer

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, avaudioplayer, avaudioengine

Is there any possibility to identify if the `AVAudioEngine` did finish its played sound? In the past I used the `AVAudioPlayer`'s function:

```
func audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying(player: AVAudioPlayer, successfully flag: Bool) {
    // Code after finished the played sound
}
```

Now I need some effects, but there is no func of `AVAudioEnginge` provided that identifies the end of the played sound.

I searched a lot, but unfortunately I found only this func in the documentation of `AVAudioEngine`:

```
var running: Bool { get }
```

My current solution will be to check the "running" boolean, if it's false the player is not playing anymore. Does somebody know a better solution for `AVAudioEngine`? Thank you very much!

Comment: My current solution: I have a NSTimer, that triggers an event every millisecon. If the AVAudioEngine reaches its end time, I trigger manually my own didFinish func.... If anybody has a better solution, please feel free to share it here. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I attach an AVAudioPlayerNode to my engine

```
player = AVAudioPlayerNode()

    let file = try! AVAudioFile(forReading: url)
    let buffer = AVAudioPCMBuffer(PCMFormat: file.processingFormat, frameCapacity: AVAudioFrameCount(file.length))

    do {
        print("read")
        try file.readIntoBuffer(buffer)
    } catch _ {
    }

engine.attachNode(player)
engine.connect(player, to: engine.mainMixerNode, format: nil)

self.player.scheduleBuffer(buffer, completionHandler: {
    print("Complete")
})

        engine.prepare()
    do {
        try engine.start()
    } catch _ {
        print("Play session Error")
    }

    player.play()
```

I hope that helps!

Comment: Happy to help! If this worked for you, please mark it as the answer.

Comment: For me this only fires when the scheduling is completed, which is almost immediately. It doesn't fire when the media playback completes.

Answer (score 2):

I also used a NSTimer as I haven't found any other solution/delegate. But it's fired only once and starts right after the audiofile ends (that means, the very first parameter "seconds" has the value of the duration of the audiofile). The selector is my "custom delegate" function.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer seems to call the completionHandler as soon as SCHEDULING is finished, not as soon as playing the audio file is finished.

As per iOS 11.0+ / macOS 10.13+ use:

```
self.player.scheduleBuffer(buffer, completionCallbackType: .dataPlayedBack completionHandler: {
    print("Complete")
})
```